# Comparar dos array de objetos

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Quisiera comparar dos arreglos de objetos en JavaScript de acuerdo a la mismo sku y mismas cantidades iguales en ambos arreglos, quisiera armar una estructura donde me muestre un arreglo con los datos correctos y los datos incorrectos de acuerdo a su cantidad adjunto el siguiente código,
los arreglos que se van a comparar son desordenados

Adjunto mi código con lo que he intentado hacer

```js
const datos =[
        {cantidad: 4, SKU: "18805008213"},
        {cantidad: 6, SKU: "18805008214"},
        {cantidad: 5, SKU: "18805008215"},
        {cantidad: 3, SKU: "18805008216"}
    ]

const skuCantEntrante=[
        {skucantidad: 5, skuEntrante: "18805008216"},
        {skucantidad: 4, skuEntrante: "18805008213"},
        {skucantidad: 5, skuEntrante: "18805008215"},
        {skucantidad: 1, skuEntrante: "18805008214"}
]
    let datoscorrectos = [];
    let datosincorrectos = [];


    for (let d = 0; d < datos.length; d++) {
    
        for (let g = 0; g < skuCantEntrante.length; g++) {
            if (skuCantEntrante[g].skuEntrante === datos[d].CODIGOINTERNO && skuCantEntrante[g].skucantidad === datos[d].cantidad) {
    
    
                datoscorrectos.push({
                "skuEntrante": skuCantEntrante[g].skuEntrante,
                "skucantidad": skuCantEntrante[g].skucantidad
                })
    
            }else if (skuCantEntrante[g].skuEntrante != datos[d].CODIGOINTERNO && skuCantEntrante[g].skucantidad != datos[d].cantidad){
    
                itemincorrect = datosincorrectos.filter((x, i) => x.skuEntrante === skuCantEntrante[g].skuEntrante);
    
                if (itemincorrect.length < 1) {
    
    
                    datosincorrectos.push({
                    "skuEntrante": skuCantEntrante[g].skuEntrante,
                    "skucantidad": skuCantEntrante[g].skucantidad
                    })
    
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    }
    console.log(datosincorrectos)
```

Comment: Muéstranos tu código ... Edita tu pregunta y agregalo por favor

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora? Y, a qué te refieres con los datos incorrectos? Solo quieres saber si los arrays contienen los mismos "SKU" o quieres saber la cantidad en la que difiere cada elemento?

Comment: ya edite el codigo amigos

Comment: @JoseAntonyMundacaAngeles falta explicar lo que sería correcto e incorrecto para tu lógica como te indico IIsanchez

Comment: el primer array me viene de la BD y el segundo lo armo yo ,
lo unico que quiero es una estructura para saber cuales son los correctos e incorrectos en base al sky y cantidad

Comment: Pero aun no se entiende, cual es la condicion para que uno sea correcto y el otro no. Mencionas la cantidad y sky pero cuales son las condiciones para considerar un registro correcto u otro no =/

Comment: Podrias agregar los valores que esperas que devuelva tu algoritmo

Comment: un registro correcto es cuando un SKU tiene la misma cantidad en ambos arreglos

Comment: me tiene que devolver 2 arreglos el primer arreglo con los mismos datos que existen en ambos arreglos , y el segundo con datos diferentes de ambos arreglos

Comment: de donde sale CODIGOINTERNO

Comment: @noseJ el primer arreglo viene de la base de datos y el segundo lo armo yo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)** que te ayuda a condicionar los registros que deseas retornar

```js
const datos = [
        { cantidad: 4, SKU: "18805008213" },
        { cantidad: 6, SKU: "18805008214" },
        { cantidad: 5, SKU: "18805008215" },
        { cantidad: 3, SKU: "18805008216" }
    ]

    const skuCantEntrante = [
        { skucantidad: 5, skuEntrante: "18805008216" },
        { skucantidad: 4, skuEntrante: "18805008213" },
        { skucantidad: 5, skuEntrante: "18805008215" },
        { skucantidad: 1, skuEntrante: "18805008214" }
    ]
    
    const right = []
    // Recorres ambos arreglos y aplicas la condición que deseas
    datos.filter((d) => {
        skuCantEntrante.filter((s) => {
            if (d.cantidad === s.skucantidad && d.SKU === s.skuEntrante) {
                right.push(d)
            }
        })
    })

    // Una vez obtenidos los registros correctos, puedes filtrar nuevamente el arreglo omitiendo los mismos
    const wrong = datos.filter(d => !right.includes(d))
    console.log(right)
    console.log(wrong)
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: El algoritmo que usas realiza una cantidad de interacciones equivalente a la multiplicación de los elementos del arreglo 1 por los del arreglo 2 más la cantidad de elementos del arreglo 1, creo que aparte de que el código cumpla su función, debería tener un margen de performance aceptable

Answer (score 3):

## Observación

Si lo que deseas es compara los dos arreglos de objetos, te recomendaria que indexes alguno de los dos usando la función `Array.prototype.reduce`, de forma tal que la comparación pueda realizarse objeto a objeto, es decir, que la cantidad máxima de iteraciones que realices sea equivalente a la suma de la cantidad de elementos de los dos arreglos, y no tengas que por cada objeto del primer arreglo, iterar todos los objetos del segundo arreglo para buscar el correspondiente, lo cual seria equivalente al numero de iteraciones máximas resultante de la suma de la cantidad de elementos del arreglo uno mas la sumatoria de la cantidad total de elementos del arreglo dos menos el indice actual del ciclo mas uno (teniendo en cuenta que parte desde el espacio 0).

## TL;DR

Te dejo esta pieza de código que puedes usar para entender la lógica y ajustarla:

```
const data1 = [
    {cantidad: 4, sku: "18805008213"},
    {cantidad: 6, sku: "18805008214"},
    {cantidad: 5, sku: "18805008215"},
    {cantidad: 3, sku: "18805008216"}
]

const data2 = [
    {cantidad: 5, sku: "18805008216"},
    {cantidad: 4, sku: "18805008213"},
    {cantidad: 5, sku: "18805008215"},
    {cantidad: 1, sku: "18805008214"}
]

// Se reduce el arreglo data2 para formar un indice
const index = data2.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return {
        ...prev,
        [curr.sku]: curr.cantidad
    }
},
{})

// Se reduce el arreglo data1 comparandolo respecto al indice
const res = data1.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    // Si las cantidades son iguales se agrega el objeto a los correctos
    if (index[curr.sku] === curr.cantidad) {
        return {
            right: [...prev.right, curr],
            wrong: prev.wrong
        }
    }
    // De lo contrario se agrega a los incorrectos
    return {
        right: prev.right,
        wrong: [...prev.wrong, curr]
    }
},
{
    right: [],
    wrong: []
})
```

La salida que obtendrás sera un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```
{ right:
   [ { cantidad: 4, sku: '18805008213' },
     { cantidad: 5, sku: '18805008215' } ],
  wrong:
   [ { cantidad: 6, sku: '18805008214' },
     { cantidad: 3, sku: '18805008216' } ] }
```